# Basic QoS policy for Dell 6248 switches

Tags: switch, dell, qos

My cisco edge router tags all incoming packets as IP precedence 0, 3, and 5 depending on their priority. How can I add a matching QoS configuration on the switch so that packets are prioritized appropriately?